# Split items using ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

This is the XAML:

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScenarioName}" Header="Scenario Name" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScenarioType}" Header="Scenario Type" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Well names" Width="175">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Wells}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>-->                                                  
                                                    <Button Width="60" Margin="0 0 0 3">Test 1</Button>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StartPeriod}" Header="Start period" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EndPeriod}" Header="End period" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Lagged}" Header="Lagged" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Detrended}" Header="Detrended" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MinimumMonths}" Header="Length of continuous months" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CorrelatedWells}" Header="Correlated wells" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Excluded Wells">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExcludedWells}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And it looks like:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xpse8n&s=6

The questions is whether there is an easy to group the "Test1" buttons under Well names(in groups of,let say, 5 items) because the volume of well names can be quite big and neither horizontal nor vertical wrapping helps.

many thanks,
elias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can always add a new property to your ViewModel

```
 public IEnumerable<Well> SomeWells
 { get { return Wells.Take(5); }
```

and change your ItemsSource binding to use this instead.

Example here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE.TAKE%60%601%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ListBox to let the user scroll through the buttons like:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Well names" Width="175">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox>
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                               <Button></Button>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
           </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but it sounds like you want something like 5 buttons in a row, and automatically wrapping to the next row every 5 buttons.

To make it work with a `WrapPanel`, you should give your panel a `Width` that is 5x with width of your buttons so it will draw 5 of them, then wrap to the next line

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel Width="300" Orientation="Vertical"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Another alternative if you don't know your Button width ahead of time is to use a `UniformGrid` with 5 Columns. I think you also need to set the Row count to something larger than you ever expect your collection to be

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="100" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Another alternative for defining the Row count is to expose a property in your data model that contains the number of rows you'll need, and binding the Rows property to it.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="{Binding RowCount}" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I can't remember if `UniformGrid.Rows` is a DependencyProperty or not, but if not then you can create an `AttachedProperty` instead that you can bind to and that will modify the `UniformGrid.Rows` property (for an example, see [this code for Attached Properties for a Grid's Rows and Columns](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/))